# Dask Distributed client takes to long to initialize in jupyter lab

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed, jupyter-lab

Trying to initialize a client with local cluster in Jupyter lab but hangs. This behaviour happens for python 3.5 and jupyter lab 0.35.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed
from distributed import Client
from distributed import LocalCluster
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Cluster(cluster)
client
```

versions of the tools :

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

And the jupyter lab version is

```
pip list |grep jupyter
jupyter            1.0.0  
jupyter-client     5.2.3  
jupyter-console    6.0.0  
jupyter-core       4.4.0  
jupyterlab         0.35.3 
jupyterlab-server  0.2.0
```

Dask version

```
pip list |grep dask
dask               0.20.0
```

What could be wrong?

EDIT: No exception on the terminal while trying to initialize client
Interrupting the Kernel gives the following exceptions:
Inside jupyter:

```
distributed.nanny - ERROR - Failed to restart worker after its process exited
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 291, in _on_exit
    yield self.instantiate()
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 226, in instantiate
    self.process.start()
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
raise self._exception
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py", line 370, in start
    yield self.process.start()
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distributed/process.py", line 35, in _call_and_set_future
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/avlach/virtualenvs/staistics3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/distributed/process.py", line 184, in _start
    process.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/context.py", line 281, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_forkserver.py", line 36, in __init__
        super().__init__(process_obj)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 20, in __init__
        self._launch(process_obj)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_forkserver.py", line 52, in _launch
        self.sentinel, w = forkserver.connect_to_new_process(self._fds)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/forkserver.py", line 66, in connect_to_new_process
    client.connect(self._forkserver_address)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

and on the terminal

```
Kernel interrupted: 1e7da6ed-2137-41ce-818e-3484c0a659cc
fd_event_list = self._epoll.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: If you kill the kernel or check the terminal output do you see any exception that may suggest where it is hanging?

Comment: Will check it on Monday...it is on my business laptop :)

Comment: could you please transcribe the image, to make it easy for search indices and seeing-impaired follk?

Comment: Sure, a how to would be good :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this, so I'm guessing there is something different on the networking side of things of your setup.